# How are decision trees in random forest algorithms made?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, decision-tree

I was suddenly presented with the profound question of how does a computer generate a decision tree.

For example, consider the problem of predicting a specific flower species using the random forest algorithm. There are two specific attributes of a flower (petal width, petal length) that distinguish the species.

In terms of the flower problem, when using sclearn's Python decisiontreemaker(), how does the computer figure out what petal width and petal length to create the tree? Also, does a random forest algorithm create these decision trees by brute forcing and testing every single variation of a tree by weighing entrophy?

Comment: Oh my bad I might have misunderstood the question, if you are asking how it finds the exact value to split at since the variables are continuous you can imagine graphs of the entropy vs each variable and you can find the min point of entropy using calculus. The actual implementation is probably very complex

Answer (score 1):

Lets make it a bit simple; say you have 2 classes `C1` and `C2` and 1 feature `X`;

```py
X = [0,1,2,3,
     4,5,6,7]
y = ["C1","C1","C1","C1",
     "C2","C2","C2","C2"]
```

we can easily see that if `X<4` the we output `C1` else `C2`.

So the way we do is, we check, for all features, "at which splitting point do we best seperate the (two) classes" or "at which splitting point do we create the purest nodes" (nodes that mostly contains one class). How we define "purity" is based on e.g `gini` or `entropy`.

Theres ways to optimize how to find those splits e.g by sorting the features first (take our example above, theres no need to check the split [0,1] since both of them contains `C1` i.e the first split to consider should be between [3,4] since we have `C1` to the left and `C2` to the right).

If we then have 3 classes instead

```py
X = [0,1,2,3,
     4,5,6,7,
     8,9, 10]
y = ["C1","C1","C1","C1",
     "C2","C2","C2","C2",
     "C3","C3","C3"]
```

we write our own "tree"

```py
def predict(X):
    if X<4:
        return "C1"
    if X<8:
        return "C2"
    return "C3"
```

which now looks a bit more like the decision tree we know.